# Unity changing from game object to ui Image

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, gameobject

In unity I am fetching a UI image through `GameObject.Find()` However when I try to change the value of another image component to the result of the game object find I get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Image' \[Assembly-CSharp\]csharp(CS0029)
```

Code:

```
Image image;

image = GameObject.Find("the other image");
```

Is there a way to fetch a UI Image game object through just it's name without it being set to a generic game object?

Comment: You mean `GameObject.Find("the other image").GetComponent<Image>()` ...? o.O .. the error sounds quite self-explanatory to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to assign the value of a image to a gameObject, you simply need to get the image

```
Image image;

var imageGameObject = GameObject.Find("the other image");

if(imageGameObject == null)
{
    //couldn't find the gameobject 
}

image = imageGameObject.GetComponenet<Image>();
```

to get the actual image component

Comment: Has nothing to do with a `Sprite` so far though ;)

Comment: oh yes, my bad lol